# Disable recurring notifications in MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I've made quite a problem for myself here..

I wanted to see if notifications from my application being run in Xcode would continue to display at one minute intervals even after the application was terminated. The answer was yes. Unfortunately, I had this code running in the `viewDidLoad()` function, so the application doubled up on the one minute intervals of the notification. I now have over one million notifications, and I have no idea how to disable them in the application. I currently have turned off notifications in System Preferences to prevent the massive CPU usage caused by this.

My question: 
What is the MacOS equivalent of (iOS Swift 3) `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.removeScheduledNotification(notification)
```

Thanks

EDIT: Added the original code

```
            var notification = NSUserNotification()
            notification.title = "Charge Level"
            notification.informativeText = "\(self.BatteryLevel.intValue)%"
            notification.hasActionButton = true
            notification.deliveryTimeZone = NSTimeZone.local
            var date = Date()
            date.minute = 1
            notification.deliveryDate = date
            NSUserNotificationCenter.default.scheduleNotification(notification)
```

UPDATE: Apple Support didn't seem to understand the problem and I got nowhere with their help, and I now have a couple billion notifications, despite my turning them off in the System Preferences. Really need help here!!

Comment: This has become quite out of hand... Going to see if Apple support can help at all..

Comment: You are not showing all relevant lines of code.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, I found that deleting the notification center cache worked. Below is what worked in Terminal.

```
cd $TMPDIR
cd ..
cd 0
sudo rm -rf ./com.apple.notificationcenter
killall NotificationCenter; killall usernoted
```